# there is one row in table but it is showing some empty row in table?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

i am returning one row in sectionForRow delegate method . but Table having one row plus some empty row with same height . it is possible to change the empty rows height ?

Comment: returning no of Rows in rowForSection dataSource method

Answer (score 1):

you can set the height for your nonempty table rows according to you in heightForRowAtIndexPath method and empty rows set their height by default.

for this you need to implement some check since you having only one row therfore code looks like

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  if(indexPath.row==1)
   return 50;  //accordingly.

return 70;//accordingly
}
```

If you have any array for showing the row then if statement change (look like)

```
if(indexPath.row==[yourArray count])
```

Comment: the Empty row is displaying by default. because it is default property

Comment: in this case height for row for empty row wont work for empty row .

Comment: hows you did that can you please tell me.

Comment: i have created one more section which have one row with height 0